# Javascript .contentDocument returning null for external SVG file

Tags: javascript, image, svg, iframe, console.log

I want to load an SVG image from an external server and manipulate the code inside before storing it locally. When trying this following code, I get the following image (see attached image). The first `console.log` is fine and dandy but the second one is returning null. I have been trying to get this to work for hours.

```
<object data="http://maxhenryxie.com/img/girl3.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="girl_large"></object>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var svgObject = document.getElementById('girl_large');
    console.log(svgObject);
    console.log(svgObject.contentDocument);
  });
</script>
```

I have also tried using `<iframe src="http://maxhenryxie.com/img/girl3.svg" id="girl_large"></iframe>` instead of using the `<object>` tag. And I have tried fetching the SVG image from both local directories and using external link, the only thing I haven't tried yet are different browsers, but other than that I am really running out of ideas.

[image]

Comment: Is `maxhenryxie.com` a different domain from your application? In general, JavaScript can't access content from other domains.

Comment: Yes it is a different domain, but it is also not working when I do it completely locally. I saw a mentioning on a Mozilla Firefox forum that contentDocument doesn't work when completely locally either.

Comment: Now I am running the Javascript from within the same domain as the image. But still, same result.

Comment: Hi, struggling with the same problem. Did anyone solve this ?